# Filtering the Query to get string containing a constant followed by special character?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am working with a project where a requirement which i face is as follows
I have some scenario to check as follows
The input in database will be a String Starting with constant character QWER it can be followed by number,character set and even by a special character like _,# and so on .
sample inputs are QWER0000001,QWERD00909,QWER32_333,QWER32-333 and so on

I need to filter all only the values that contain QWER and followed by number only from above cases expected result is only QWER0000001
 the query i tried in is as follows

```
select c.request_Id
from TABLE c
where UPPER(c.request_Id) not like 'QWER%[A-Z]'
  and  c.request_Id  like 'QWER[0-9]%'
```

now it filters the the data that contain special characters also . how to filter the unwanted spl charecters set .expecting a query that forks fine in both oracle and sql

Comment: Both Oracle and SQL? Do you perhaps mean and MS SQL Server? (Oracle SQL is also SQL...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `regexp_like` with a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   c
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(request_id, '^QWER[0-9]+$');
```